# SpriteSheet Animation with XNA

Tags: xna, c#, sprites, spritesheet

Hi i'm working on my First 2D Game with XNA and I have a little problem.
To give a *running* effect to my Sprite, I scroll through a *SpriteSheet* with this code(running right):

```
if (AnimationDelay == 6)
{
    if (CurrentFrameR.X < SheetSizeR.X)
    {
        ++CurrentFrameR.X;
    }
    else
    {
        CurrentFrameR.Y++;
        CurrentFrameR.X = 1;
    }

    if (CurrentFrameR.Y >= SheetSizeR.Y)
    {
        CurrentFrameR.X = 0;
        CurrentFrameR.Y = 0;
    }

    AnimationDelay = 0;
}
else
{
    AnimationDelay += 1;
}

xPosition += xDeplacement;
```

And these are the objects used :

```
Point FrameSizeR = new Point(29, 33);
Point SheetSizeR = new Point(5, 1);
Point CurrentFrameR = new Point(0, 0);
int AnimationDelay = 0;
```

I have the same Code with different *SpriteSheet* when the sprite is running Left.
Everything is working fine I'd say 90% of the time but the other 10% the sprite animation stays on one Frame of the *SpriteSheet*, on both directions(left and right) and it stays stuck until I close the program.
The thing is I can't quite figure out why since it never happens at the same moment..Sometimes after 10,15,30 seconds and sometimes even on boot!
Any idea why?
Thanks in advance and let me know if you need any other parts of the code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I bet it's because `AnimationDelay` manages to make it past 6 somehow. I'd change the if statement to:

```
if (AnimationDelay >= 6)
```

Comment: Wow.. well seen! Completely solve the thing 
+1 to you sir and thanks a lot !:)

Comment: @PhaDaPhunk - If that was actually the problem, you probably want to figure out why it was going over six, since that indicates there's something incorrect or unexpected happening in your code.

Answer (score 3):

John's question will do, however you might still want to look at doing it 'correctly' in the first place.

```
// It's important we make the current frame a float; because something like 0.1f
// might be added to it at really high framerates.
// This will refer to each frame as if the tileset was actually a single lines of frames.
// (Even though they are not)
private float CurrentFrame;

********** In your update/draw method. **********

// Animate your sprite at 15 FPS.
CurrentFrame += gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds * 15;

// Constrain CurrentFrame to the number of frames available.
// (This replaces your if; frame = 0; etc.)
CurrentFrame %= SheetSizeR.X * SheetSizeR.Y;

// Find out the X and Y position of the current cell we want, from
// CurrentFrame. You must use integral division here - as it has a
// few properties that makes mapping a 1D index to a 2D array more
// straight-forward.
CurrentFrameR.X = (int)CurrentFrame % (int)SheetSizeR.X;
CurrentFrameR.Y = (int)CurrentFrame / (int)SheetSizeR.Y;
```

Comment: (I'd just like to point out that `CurrentFrame` should be renamed to `currentFrame` in case people follow Microsoft's coding guidelines. Which would be nice, since you're working with XNA, and others are going to read your code..)
(Private variables should start with a lower case)

Comment: @Zolomon that's really pedantic - I was keeping stuff consistent with his question; for all I know his stuff is public. Also, Microsoft uses `_currentFrame`, `m_CurrentFrame` and `m_currentFrame`.

Comment: I realized that after a few minutes, I meant no disrespect! I suppose I should've commented on his question first. :)

Comment: @Zolomon I never take on people about how they write code; unless I have to work with them on that code. If it's a personal project you can name your variables after your dead pets for all I care :).